# Monitor all processes in Linux with telegraf and grafana

Tags: linux, monitoring, grafana, telegraf

I have a task to configure monitoring of all processes in a Linux system with Telegraf and Grafana. But there is some issue that there are many processes in a system.

For gathering information about processes I have used Procstat plugin.

**Procstat plugin configuration**

```
[[inputs.procstat]]
  pattern = ".*"
```

As you can see plugin will gather information about all processes, but how can I configure it in Grafana with one query from InfluxDB. If I will configuring query for new process each time it will be appearing, this work will take significant time and won't be scalable.

[Grafana panel configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X30jp.png)

Answer (score 2):

Solution: GROUP BY tag(process_name).

[Grafana panel config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTbzl.png)